# Having trouble making a query builder work properly for finding all posts from last 7 days

Tags: doctrine, query-builder

I'm using Doctrine query builder to try to find all occurrences from the last 7 days.  Here's my code:

```
return $this->createPublishedQueryBuilder('content')
                    ->andWhere('content.date BETWEEN :today AND :sevenDaysAgo')
                    ->setParameter('today', new \DateTime())
                    ->setParameter('sevenDaysAgo', new \DateTime('-7 day'))
                    ->orderBy('content.pageviews.weekly', 'desc')
                    ->setMaxResults($count)
                    ->getQuery()
                    ->getResult();
```

But it's not returning any results.  The recently added lines were the andwhere and two setparameter lines below that in order to add the additional search functionality.  Any thoughts on what's going on would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT 1:
No luck switching :today AND :sevenDaysAgo

I also forgot to mention here is the date variable:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 *
 * @Serial\SerializedName("publication_date")
 * @Serial\Type("DateTime<'Y-m-d'>")
 * @Serial\Groups({"list", "fixture", "detail", "email"})
 *
 * @Assert\Date()
 *
 * @var DateTime
 */
protected $date;
```

Comment: Try changing the order of the date parameters in the query.

Comment: @msg no luck :[

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using a between query I would suggest using a higher-than method.

```
return $this->createPublishedQueryBuilder('content')
                      ->andWhere('content.date > :sevenDaysAgo')
                      ->setParameter('sevenDaysAgo', new \DateTime('-7 day'))
                      ->orderBy('content.pageviews.weekly', 'desc')
                      ->setMaxResults($count)
                      ->getQuery()
                      ->getResult();
```

otherwise I see no errors in your query. I guess "createPublishedQueryBuilder" is intentional and an abstract form of "createQueryBuilder" ?